# Is there a solution to transform values, after getOne?

Tags: react-admin

Need to transform fetched object, (e.g {..., "key": {"**keyName**": "**keyValue**"}}) need to transform {..., [{"name": "**keyName**", "value": "**keyValue**"}]}

```
const { field }: any = useController({ name: 'headers', rules: { required: 'The field is required' } });

useEffect(() => {
    const newValue: { headerName: string; headerValue: any; }[] = []
        Object.keys(field.value).forEach(el => {
        newValue.push({ 'headerName': el, 'headerValue': field.value[el] });
    });
    // NOT UPDATING
    field.onChange(newValue)
}, []);
```

Comment: The most suitable place for this is your DataProvider, you can make a custom version based on the source texts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The `withLifecycleCallbacks` helper](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/withLifecycleCallbacks.html) is made for this. This function allows you to adds logic to an existing `dataProvider` for particular resources, using `pre-` and `post-` event handlers like `afterGetOne` for instance.

For instance:

```js
const baseDataProvider = myDataProvider('http://path.to.my.api/');
export const dataProvider = withLifecycleCallbacks(baseDataProvider, [
    {
        resource: 'posts',
        afterGetOne: async (result, dataProvider) => {
            return transform(result); // transform the result and return it
        },
    },
]);
```

Hope this helps :)